# spring cloud config multiple profiles

Tags: spring-cloud-config

I want to setup multiple profiles for my spring_cloud_config_server.

Here is my yml file:

```
server:
  port: "2000"

spring:
  profiles:
    active: native
  application:
    name: config-server
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          search-locations: file:///opt/app/configuration

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8260/eureka

logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework: INFO
---
spring:
  profiles: docker
  application:
    name: config-server
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          search-locations: file:/opt/app/configuration

server:
  port: "2000"

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://127.0.0.1:8260/eureka

logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework: INFO
```

When I run the app using the "native" profile using the following command

```
java -jar app.jar
```

or

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=native app.jar
```

The app running good. 
When I run the app using the "docker" profile using the following command

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=docker app.jar
```

The app exits with Exception:

```
ERROR o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatStarter - Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint]: Factory method 'healthEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'configServerHealthIndicator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/EnvironmentRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'configServerHealthIndicator' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.CompositeConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setEnvironmentRepos' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultEnvironmentRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/DefaultRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to configure a uri for the git repository.
```

The root cause is:

```
Exception: You need to configure a uri for the git repository.
```

Is my yml file correct for the two profiles? Did I miss anything to make it work for both profiles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default behavior of Spring Cloud Config Server is logic for `git` profile. So it is trying to find property `spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri` which you don't have.

To fix you issue you need to have `native` profile enabled for both cases. Native configuration starts working only when 'native' profile is active:

```
public class EnvironmentRepositoryConfiguration { 
......
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(EnvironmentRepository.class)
@Profile("native")
class NativeRepositoryConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public NativeEnvironmentRepository 
     nativeEnvironmentRepository(NativeEnvironmentRepositoryFactory factory,
        NativeEnvironmentProperties environmentProperties) {
    return factory.build(environmentProperties);
  }
}
......
```

see more here:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/spring-cloud-config-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/EnvironmentRepositoryConfiguration.java#L215

Since Spring Boot supports multiple profiles in your particular case I would recommend to use "including" additional profiles feature of Spring Boot. See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html#boot-features-adding-active-profiles

Basically your `application.yml` configuration will look like this:

```
spring.profiles: some-profile-1
spring.profiles.include:
  - native
# specific configuration for 'some-profile-1'

---

spring.profiles: some-profile-2
spring.profiles.include:
  - native
# specific configuration for 'some-profile-2'
```

And you will just enable active profile by passing `-Dspring.profiles.active=some-profile-1 (or 2)`